# Find the general solution of this differential equation $2U_x-U_y+4U_z+U=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Can someone please check my answer of this question?
Tha calculus was too long so I preferred to avoid writing it down.

**The question : **

Find the general solution of this differential equation .

$$2U_x-U_y+4U_z+U=0$$
$$U=U(x,y,z)$$

**My answer is **
$$U(x,y,z)=e^{\frac{-x}{2}}.f(8x+8y-2z,8x+8y-2z)$$

Actually in this book I’m reading it only talked about $U(x,y)$ so I just used the same logic to do the one with three unknowns and I can be very wrong.
If I am I would be really thrilled if someone could drop a relevant link for me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know what you mean by $f(8x+8y-2z,8x+8y-2z)$. Is $f$ an arbitrary function of two variables? But you're only evaluating it at points where the two arguments are equal? So it's really a function of one variable?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes is that wrong?

Comment: Well, it's strange to write a function of one variable as if it's a function of two variables. Why would you do that? Anyway, have you checked to see whether, say, $U(x,y,z)=(4x+4y-z)e^{-x/2}$ satisfies the PDE?

Answer (score 1):

The Lagrange-Charpit equations for the PDE
$$
2U_x-U_y+4U_z+U=0 \tag{1}
$$
are
$$
\frac{dx}{2}=\frac{dy}{-1}=\frac{dz}{4z}=\frac{dU}{-U}. \tag{2}
$$
Solving them, we find
$$
\frac{dx}{2}=\frac{dy}{-1} \implies x+2y=C_1, \tag{3}
$$
$$
\frac{dy}{-1}=\frac{dz}{4z} \implies 4y+z=C_2, \tag{4}
$$
$$
\frac{dx}{2}=\frac{dU}{-U} \implies U=C_3e^{-x/2}. \tag{5}
$$
Combining $(3)$-$(5)$, we obtain
$$
U(x,y,z)=e^{-x/2}f(x+2y,4y+z), \tag{6}
$$
where $f$ is an arbitrary differentiable function of two variables.